# Makefile count how many files

Tags: c++, makefile

I am making a makefile that compiles some .cpp files but i want it to be "beautiful".
So i try to add current index compiling:
(eg: Compiling 10nth out of 150 total files.)
I successfully did the 10nth out of part, but i cannot find a way to get how many total files are in makefile's directory (in my case how many .cpp's).
What i want is to get this 150 number.
So my Question (and i am really curious WHY no one has ever asked) is, how to get how many .cpp files are in this (makefile's) directory.
I hope this question helps other people as well in the future.

Comment: `make -n` generates a list of all commands `make` would execute, after figuring out which files are out of date. It should be a matter of writing a simple script that filters the output of `make -n`, counting the number of compilation commands, then inserting an `echo` before each one, then executing the script.

Comment: This would become a bit meaningless when using `make -j` to run multiple jobs in parallel.

And silence is golden, the most beautiful output of `make` should be there when running `make -s`: No output at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like this using GNU Make:

```bash
SOURCES := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)

NO_OF_FILES := $(words $(SOURCES))
```

Various text processing functions are [documented here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html)

Comment: With a bit of configuration for my needs WORKED PERFECT! Also i like compressed code so i made it oneline, if anyone needs: NO_OF_FILES := $(words $(wildcard source/path/*.cpp))

Comment: This gives total number of files, not the number of necessary compilations